# Drag&Drop images in the Summernote Text Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, summernote

I want to understand if I can do Drag&Drop image in my text editor [plugin](http://summernote.org/) . I'm using angularjs v1.5.0 with it. When image was uploaded I want to have possible dragging it.

There are a lot of solution for dragging, but I did not find how can I do this when there is the text inside. For example: 
There is some text and image in the editor "*< img src='lala.jpg'> Some Text Here*" and after dragging I need that "*Some Text < img src='lala.jpg'> Here*". I included drag&drop plugin and image became with styling position: relative, top|left. Yes, its dragging, but without text floating. What can I do with it?

Thanks for any help or ideas

Answer (score 0):

set image tag do draggable and when you fire the 'Drop' event, you will get x and y position for the image. Calculate your string width and height and break the text where image should be placed. Then, put the  tag exactly where it should be...

[Calculate text width with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript)